# Determining Statistical Significance of Features in Frequency Domain Data

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, spectral-analysis

In [this](http://paos.colorado.edu/research/wavelets/bams_79_01_0061.pdf) paper, the authors state (pg. 70):

> The corresponding distribution for the *local wavelet power spectrum* is $$\frac{|W_n(s)|^2}{\sigma^2} \implies \frac{1}{2}P_k\chi_2^2 \tag{18} $$ ...After finding an appropriate background spectrum and choosing a
>   particular confidence for $\chi^2$ such as 95%, one can then calculate (18)
>   at each scale and construct 95% confidence contour lines.

In eqn. 18 (pg. 70), if $P_k$ is 1 or $\alpha = 0$ in eqn. 16 (pg. 69), i.e., in the case of white noise, how does one go from having the power spectrum data in the LHS, $|W_n(s)|^2/\sigma^2$,  to obtaining the 95% confidence contour lines, as shown in fig. 1(b) (pg. 62)?

Here, $\sigma^2$ is the variance of time series whose continuous wavelet transform is given by $W_n(s)$.